# How to show the bootstrap card body data when we click on the particular tab

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I my angular application I have placed the bootstrap cards with heading and data showing data in horizontally (used horizontal cards).

**component.html**

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="card" id="dd" style="max-width: 800px;">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-sm-3" >
                <h5>heading 1</h5>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>info 1.1</p>                         
                    <p>info 1.2</p>                         
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" >
                <h5>heading 2</h5>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>info 2.1</p>
                    <p>info 2.2</p>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" >
                <h5>heading 3</h5>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>info 3.1</p>
                    <p>info 2.2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Now I want to make the headings headings-1,2,3.. as tabs.and when we click on that particular tab the data (i.e info) will be come like info 1.1,info 1.2,info 1.3 etc (has to come horizontally as above)if the heading another data info it has to come another card(after above card)like info 1.11,info 1.12 etc.and it is continued same for other headings also)can anyone please help me for this I am new to this bootstrap.**

I want to show the data in horizontal cars with each tab clicked.And show one more info if it has two info data inside the heading.

Comment: Do you want to display tabs? When you click on the tab, the data should be displayed horizontally?  Is this your question?

Comment: You may helps [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tab-content&stacked=h)

Comment: Yes, the data should be shown in horizontal  cards.Can you help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap classes for the tabs.

```
<div class="container">
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="tab-A" href="#pane-A" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">heading 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="tab-B" href="#pane-B" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">heading 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="tab-C" href="#pane-C" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">heading 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>


<div id="content" class="tab-content" role="tablist">
    <div id="pane-A" class="card tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-A">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-A">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <!-- Note: `data-parent` removed from here -->
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-A" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-A">
                    Collapsible Group Item A
                </a>
            </h5>
        </div>

        <!-- Note: New place of `data-parent` -->
        <div id="collapse-A" class="collapse show" data-parent="#content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-A">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>info 1.1</p>                         
                <p>info 1.2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pane-B" class="card tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-B">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-B">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-B" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-B">
                    Collapsible Group Item B
                </a>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-B" class="collapse" data-parent="#content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-B">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>info 2.1</p>
                <p>info 2.2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pane-C" class="card tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-C">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-C">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-C" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-C">
                    Collapsible Group Item C
                </a>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-C" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" data-parent="#content" aria-labelledby="heading-C">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>info 3.1</p>
                <p>info 2.2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/shradhaa/pen/RwaQpZe)

Comment: Thanks@Shradha,I have used the tabs but I have to show the data(info 1.1,info 1.2..)in horizontal card and if the heading has two data info's it has to shown in another card (info 1.11,info 1.22..)can you help me for this.